# How to handle websocket responses in a sequential way using an interval in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets

I'm writing a card game which has a single and a multiplayer mode. In case of a single player game a script generates moves in response to the player's moves. My problem is that this script moves in a blink of an eye and I want the player to feel that the AI is "thinking" on its move thus wait with each response before displaying it for 2 seconds.

Since I'm using a browser + server architecture with a javascript client this waiting is rather problematic. The code I have currently is not behaving the way I want it to be. The idea is that when a response arrives from the websocket client and it is generated by the ai the response is pushed into a queue. And there is an interval which runs every 2 seconds and tries to pop form that queue. Here is my code:

```
        // interval
        var responseQueue = [];
        $interval(function () {
            var response = responseQueue.shift();
            if (response !== undefined) {
                processResponse(response);
            }
        }, OPPONENT_MOVE_REFRESH_INTERVAL);

        // websocket response
        SocketFactory.subscribe("/user/queue/game.gameResponse", function (response) {
            var res = JSON.parse(response.body);
            // the current player moved, refreshing view
            if ($scope.username === res.currentPlayerId) {
                processResponse(res);
            } else {
                // the opponent moved (the ai in this case)
                responseQueue.push(res);
            }
        });
```

What I get is something which seems like random behavior. Cards are appearing but not in 2 second intervals and data is lost sometimes. What am I doing wrong?

**Note that** it is possible for a player to move more than once so sometimes I get 2-3 AI moves in quick succession.

Comment: if you use push() to fill, use pop() to empty. or use unshift() instead of push(), otherwise your queue will not be executed in the right order. personally, i would just setTimeout() the response action and avoid the queue complexity.

Comment: i'm saying you don't need a queue at all. replace `responseQueue.push(res);` with `setTimeout(function(){ processResponse(res); }, 2000)` to delay each action 2 seconds. three quick actions will still happen quickly (clustered together), but the whole sequence won't begin until after a 2-second pause, which should be very natural if understand your game.

Comment: I don't want clustered actions because the player needs to understand why each move happened.

Comment: i see. you might consider a different simplification that replaces the interval with a named method (i like _next()_) sporting a conditionally-self-calling tail; something like `if(responseQueue.length) setTimeout(arguments.callee, 2000)`, which ensures a consistent 2-second delay from the socket response and between actions.

Comment: Can you put that as an answer please? Another thing. I read the documentation of `unshift`, `shift`, `push` and `pop` and what I want is to push at the end and pop at the front (as a Queue should behave) so I need to use `push` and `shift` respectively here! *(I need FIFO and not LIFO behavior)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like the following should work better because it ensures a delay between the response and on-screen action, instead of just a delay based on the last previously scheduled view update. i'm still not sure if this will stop your missing cards (your code actually looks ok), but it will make the delays more consistent.

```
 // interval
    var responseQueue = [];
    function next() {
        var response = responseQueue.shift();
        if (response !== undefined) {
            processResponse(response);
        }
        if(responseQueue.length) next.timer=setTimeout(next, 2000);
    }

    // websocket response
    SocketFactory.subscribe("/user/queue/game.gameResponse", function (response) {
        var res = JSON.parse(response.body);
        // the current player moved, refreshing view
        if ($scope.username === res.currentPlayerId) {
            processResponse(res);
        } else {
            // the opponent moved (the ai in this case)
            clearTimeout(next.timer);
            responseQueue.push(res);
            next.timer=setTimeout(next, 2000);
        }
    });
```

now, nothing will happen until 2 seconds after something else.